# Subset algebraic data type, or type-level set, in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, algebraic-data-types

Suppose you have a large number of types and a large number of functions that each return "subsets" of these types.

Let's use a small example to make the situation more explicit. Here's a simple algebraic data type:

```
data T = A | B | C
```

and there are two functions `f`, `g` that return a `T`

```
f :: T
g :: T
```

For the situation at hand, assume it is important that `f` can only return a `A` or `B` and `g` can only return a `B` or `C`.

I would like to encode this in the type system. Here are a few reasons/circumstances why this might be desirable:

- Let the functions `f` and `g` have a more informative signature than just `::T`
- Enforce that implementations of `f` and `g` do not accidentally return a forbidden type that users of the implementation then accidentally use
- Allow code reuse, e.g. when helper functions are involved that only operate on subsets of type `T`
- Avoid boilerplate code (see below)
- Make refactoring (much!) easier

One way to do this is to split up the algebraic datatype and wrap the individual types as needed:

```
data A = A
data B = B
data C = C

data Retf = RetfA A | RetfB B 
data Retg = RetgB B | RetgC C

f :: Retf
g :: Retg
```

This works, and is easy to understand, but carries a lot of boilerplate for frequent unwrapping of the return types `Retf` and `Retg`.

I don't see polymorphism being of any help, here.

So, probably, this is a case for dependent types. It's not really a type-level list, rather a type-level set, but I've never seen a type-level set.

The goal, in the end, is to encode the domain knowledge via the types, so that compile-time checks are available, without having excessive boilerplate. (The boilerplate gets really annoying when there are lots of types and lots of functions.)

Answer (score 3):

Define an auxiliary sum type (to be used as a data kind) where each branch corresponds to a version of your main type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
import Data.Kind
import Data.Void
import GHC.TypeLits

data Version = AllEnabled | SomeDisabled
```

Then define a type family that maps the version and the constructor name (given as a type-level `Symbol`) to the type `()` if that branch is allowed, and to the empty type `Void` if it's disallowed.

```
type Enabled :: Version -> Symbol -> Type
type family Enabled v ctor where
    Enabled SomeDisabled "C" = Void
    Enabled _ _ = ()
```

Then define your type as follows:

```
type T :: Version -> Type
data T v = A !(Enabled v "A")
         | B !(Enabled v "B")
         | C !(Enabled v "C")
```

(The strictness annotations are there to help the exhaustivity checker.)

Typeclass instances can be derived, but separately for each version:

```
deriving instance Show (T AllEnabled)
deriving instance Eq (T AllEnabled)
deriving instance Show (T SomeDisabled)
deriving instance Eq (T SomeDisabled)
```

Here's an example of use:

```
noC :: T SomeDisabled
noC = A ()

main :: IO ()
main = print $ case noC of
    A _ -> "A"
    B _ -> "B"
    -- this doesn't give a warning with -Wincomplete-patterns
```

This solution makes pattern-matching and construction more cumbersome, because those `()` are always there.

A variation is to have one type family per branch (as in [Trees that Grow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/11/trees-that-grow.pdf)) instead of a two-parameter type family.

Comment: The `Version` kind isn't strictly needed; one could use `Type` in combination with an open type family in order to allow for more extensibility (no need to know all possible versions beforehand).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve something like this in the past, but without much success -- I was not too satisfied with my solution.

Still, one can use GADTs to encode this constraint:

```
data TagA = IsA | NotA
data TagC = IsC | NotC
    
data T (ta :: TagA) (tc :: TagC) where
   A :: T 'IsA  'NotC
   B :: T 'NotA 'NotC
   C :: T 'NotA 'IsC

-- existential wrappers
data TnotC where TnotC :: T ta 'NotC -> TnotC
data TnotA where TnotA :: T 'NotA tc -> TnotA

f :: TnotC
g :: TnotA
```

This however gets boring fast, because of the wrapping/unwrapping of the exponentials. Consumer functions are more convenient since we can write

```
giveMeNotAnA :: T 'NotA tc -> Int
```

to require anything but an `A`. Producer functions instead need to use existentials.

In a type with many constructors, it also gets inconvenient since we have to use a GADT with many tags/parameters. Maybe this can be streamlined with some clever typeclass machinery.

Comment: Can't you avoid some of those existentials if you take the indices as just enabling/disabling individual constructors?

Comment: @dfeuer Can you elaborate? I can't see your point. Above I use an index to enable/disable `A`, and another one to enable/disable `C`. Then, if I want to return "not an `A`" I have to specify "not an `A`, could be a `C` or not" and that requires an existential. Is there some shortcut?

Comment: [Here's the idea](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/2f1a566f3a19f2e9222a98e329873921). It definitely doesn't solve everything, but maybe it's good enough for this purpose?

Comment: @dfeuer I see. That's a bit better than my approach above. IIRC, when several years ago I tried to solve this problem for a simple expression language (the tags were "no operator X inside", "maybe X") I also tried your approach. Ultimately, the main issue I faced is that the weakening "no X" -> "maybe X" required an O(N) scan of the expression. Existentials did not completely solve this either, so I scrapped the idea of encoding this constraint in the type. Anyway, the case above `A|B|C` is much simpler (since it's non recursive) and does not face this issue.

Comment: @dfeuer Perhaps one could extend the O(1) safe coercions of `Data.Coerce` to also encompass this form of "subtyping" (no-tag -> maybe-tag). IMO, it could be a nice idea for a research paper to see if this can be done safely. :-)

Comment: Yes, I've run into the retagging problem too. It's ugly for sure! It's not even just about weakening; I'd like to be able to get explicit sharing once I bring in enough evidence, rather than hoping the compiler does so really late (which surely won't happen in a situation like the one you describe). Maybe some day.

Comment: So if I understand this right the subsets are essentially binary encoded via `IsX` / `NotX`. I didn't think of that. Well, hmmm, it's not very succinct if it's `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, ....

Comment: @mcmayer Agreed. Still, if you need to express 2^N possible constraints (one for each subset of constructors), you need 2^N distinct types. Binary is the most compact notation for that. If instead, you do not really need all 2^N subsets, you may be able to find a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Giving each individual value its own type scales extremely badly, and is quite unnecessarily fine-grained.

What you probably want is just restrict the types by some *property* on their values. In e.g. Coq, that would be a [subset type](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Subset.html):

```
Inductive T: Type :=
     | A
     | B
     | C.

Definition Retf: Type := { x: T | x<>C }.
Definition Retg: Type := { x: T | x<>A }.
```

Well, Haskell has no way of expressing such value constraints, but that doesn't stop you from creating types that conceptually fulfill them. Just use newtypes:

```
newtype Retf = Retf { getRetf :: T }
mkRetf :: T -> Maybe Retf
mkRetf C = Nothing
mkRetf x = Retf x

newtype Retg = Retg { getRetg :: T }
mkRetg :: ...
```

Then in the implementation of `f`, you match for the final result of `mkRetf` and raise an error if it's `Nothing`. That way, an implementation mistake that makes it give a `C` will unfortunately not give a compilation error, but at least a runtime error from within the function that's actually at fault, rather than somewhere further down the line.

An alternative that might be ideal for you is [Liquid Haskell](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/), which does support subset types. I can't say too much about it, but it's supposedly pretty good (and will in new GHC versions have direct support).